# Spring boot application -OpenCV : Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, javacv, bytedeco-javacv

I am using OpenCV frame extraction from video in spring-boot application.
I have following openCV related mvn dependencies defined

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2-0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1-1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>openblas</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.20-1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>openblas-platform</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.20-1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
            <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
            <version>4.1-1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I run the code getting this error

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/opencv_openpnp6973620001123807679/nu/pattern/opencv/linux/x86_64/libopencv_java342.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Unable to stop the stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: you should seek help from the authors/maintainers of "OpenPNP" and "javacv" (bytedeco) -- you should also review [ask]. do some research, i.e. google the error.

Comment: It's not possible to load 2 different versions of OpenCV in the same process. You'll need to choose one or the other.